# How to match a line after a pattern of underscores

Tags: powershell

I have a file containing huge mount of data like this:

```
______________________________________________________________________

.         1-9/16 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +2.685 / O/A = -2.685
.                +2.685 /       -2.685
.                +3.935 /       -3.935
______________________________________________________________________

.         1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +0.9 / O/A = -3.237
.                +0.9 /       -3.237
.                +0.9 /       -4.487
___________________________________________________________________

.         1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +5.699 / O/A = -5.699
__________________________________________________________________

.         1-1/8 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +1.553 / O/A = -1.553
.                +2.338 /       -2.338
.                +2.513 /       -2.513
```

What I need to do is to grab the first line of text after each "_______" (underscores),

1-9/16 TCS DRILL

1-11/32 TCS DRILL

1-11/32 TCS DRILL

.....

how can I specify a pattern in powershell to match LINE using get-content or get-childitem?

I could use to match the lines without any of those characters "=" , "+", "-", but this pattern is not accurate and not working...

```
$file = 'C:\test\001.txt'

Get-Childitem $file | select-string -pattern '=','+','-' -notmatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have tried something like this with your sample data ( in the text file `$file`)

```powershell
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -split "_+" | 
    Where-Object{$_} | 
    ForEach-Object{$_ -split "`r`n" | Select -Index 2}
```

Simply reads the *whole* file at once using `-Raw` then `-split`s the file on the group of underscores. Use `Where-Object` to filter out the empty entries as there would be one at the beginning of the file.

With each chunk that is gained from that process we take it a split it up on newlines. Since the first 2 lines are empty space we use `-Index` to grab the first line of data that contains what you are looking for.

**Sample Ouput**

```powershell
.         1-9/16 TCS DRILL                  
.         1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  
.         1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  
.         1-1/8 TCS DRILL
```

To remove the leading period and following spaces we can do a small update to the loop

```powershell
ForEach-Object{($_ -split "`r`n" | Select -Index 2) -replace "^\.\s+"}
```

Comment: I made this working by `Get-Childitem $file | select-string -pattern '_' -Context 0,2 `, but this one contains `____` in results, I ll try yours. Thanks

Comment: Can I ask what does `"`r`n" ` mean ? r & n?

Comment: @RootLoop ``"`r`n"`` are the PowerShell character equivalent of carriage return and new line.

Comment: Thanks , I will dig more.

Comment: @RootLoop did you try this? Did it actually work? If not I would like to fix it.

Comment: It is working, the only thing I am trying to get rid of in result is `dot space ` in the head of each line. I am trying to use `$line.replace(". ","")` to remove it. but I still get spaces left in each line before and after text.

Comment: Ha, that simple.....one more question, what should I learn more about all those string filtering? regular exp ?

Comment: Could you help me one more time? I would like to still keep the first text line after each underscore line, but also I would like to output rest of text line in each spited group, but the number of the text lines is uncertain in each group, so I can not use `-index 2,4,5,6`....beside that, I have to remove everything till the LAST `MINUS NUMBER` in each text line (not the line -index 2), wish you can help me on this. THX

Comment: @RootLoop I suggest making a new question since this one was just about matching the one line. Also, I would like to see an specific example of what you expect which would look awful in comments.. Make that new question and I will look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you've pasted it, at least, the lines are underscores `_`, not hyphens `-`. Try adding `'_'` to the list of things to not match