# Splitting multi-line string groups and outputting selected fields

Tags: string, powershell

The file contains a huge amount of data like this:

```
______________________________________________________________________

.         1-9/16 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +2.685 / O/A = -2.685
.                +2.685 /       -2.685
.                +3.935 /       -3.935


______________________________________________________________________

.         1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +0.9 / O/A = -3.237
.                +0.9 /       -3.237
.                +0.9 /       -4.487


______________________________________________________________________

.         1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +5.699 / O/A = -5.699


______________________________________________________________________

.         1-1/8 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +1.553 / O/A = -1.553
.                +2.338 /       -2.338
.                +2.513 /       -2.513


______________________________________________________________________

.         1-1/16 TCS DRILL                  

.          CUT = +3.587 / O/A = -8.074
```

[I can output the first text line after each underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353336)

```
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -split "_+" | 
    Where-Object{$_} | 
ForEach-Object{($_ -split "`r`n" | Select -Index 2) -replace "^\.\s+"}
```

However, I would also like to still keep the first text line after each underscore line, along with outputting the rest of the text line in each split group. But the number of the text lines is **uncertain** in each group, so I cannot use `-index 2,4,5,6`. Besides that, I have to remove everything till the **last negative number** in each text line (not the line -index 2, this line is the name of each group), so the output should look like this in 2 columns:

```
1-9/16 TCS DRILL
                    -2.685
                    -2.685
                    -3.935
1-11/32 TCS DRILL
                    -3.237
                    -3.237
                    -4.487
1-11/32 TCS DRILL
                    -5.699
1-1/8 TCS DRILL
                    -1.553
                    -2.338
                    -2.513
```

Comment: @Matt posted again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this then?

```powershell
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -split "_+" | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{    
    $entry = $_ -split "`r`n" 

    ($entry | Select -Index 2) -replace "^\.\s+"
    $entry | Select -Skip 3 | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
        "-$(($_ -split "-")[-1].Trim())"
    }
}
```

What we do is the same as before. Output that "tool" line in the file. Now we process each of the remaining lines of each group. Taking the lines that, again, are not empty we just split up the string into a array based on the the minus sign. The last element `[-1]` of each line should be the value you are looking for which we statically add back the `-` to the string. Use `.Trim()` to clean up the spacing for us.

**Sample Output**

```powershell
1-9/16 TCS DRILL                  
-2.685
-2.685
-3.935
1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  
-3.237
-3.237
-4.487
1-11/32 TCS DRILL                  
-5.699
1-1/8 TCS DRILL                  
-1.553
-2.338
-2.513
```

This was quick and dirty and would be better coded if we just removed all the empty lines to begin with but this does work. When I get home I might tidy it up a bit. Let me know how it goes for you.

**Round 2**

Now that I have a little more time I tried to clean this up a bit. Result should still be the same as above

```powershell
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -split "_+" | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
    $entry = $_.Split("`r`n",[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -replace "^\.\s+"
    $entry[0]
    ($entry | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace ".*-","-"
}
```

This time using `[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries` to remove the empty entries so I don't have to guess which line contains the item string. Also since `-replace` works on arrays then we can use that without the need for more `ForEach` loops. As for the last two regex strings:

- `"^\.\s+"` matches a period at the start of a string and all consecutive whitespace that follows
- `".*-"` matches everything until the last occurance of `-`

Comment: This works great and easier for me to understand. Great help, Thanks again. I will try this on more similar data to see if any error come up.

Comment: @RootLoop If you do have issues try my Round2. Should be the same thing just a little cleaner.

Comment: The second one works great too. I need to do same study on your code, also spend some time on the 2 websites you maintained earlier today :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
Get-Content $file -Delimiter ('_'*70) |
foreach {
   $_.split("`n") -match '\.+' -replace '^\.\s+' -replace '.+\s(-[0-9.]+)',"$(' '*20)`$1"
  }
```

Output using your sample data:

```
1-9/16 TCS DRILL
                    -2.685
                    -2.685
                    -3.935
1-11/32 TCS DRILL
                    -3.237
                    -3.237
                    -4.487
1-11/32 TCS DRILL
                    -5.699
1-1/8 TCS DRILL
                    -1.553
                    -2.338
                    -2.513
1-1/16 TCS DRILL
                    -8.074
```

This takes advantage of the string of - to separate each drill spec set into it's a separate string.  After that it's just a matter of removing lines and characters you don't want an inserting spaces to get the formatting like you want it.

Comment: Thanks @mjolinor, yours works too, but I still vote for Matt as best answer, because it with more detailed explanation, easier for me to understand. :)

Comment: No problem. Matt's will work fine, too.  About the only substantial advantage this has is that it will scale easily to very large files because you're not having to read the entire file into memory.  It's dealing with one drill spec record at a time in the pipeline.